# How to calculate singular moduli $\alpha_{3,n}$ of Ramanujan' s "$q_{3}$" theory?

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function, modular-function

Ramanujan's theory "$q_{3}$"

How to calculate singular moduli $t=\alpha_{3,n}$ explicitly of this?

$$\frac{\,_2F_1\big(\tfrac13,\tfrac23,1,1-t\big)}{\,_2F_1\big(\tfrac13,\tfrac23,1,t\big)} =\sqrt{n}$$

Where can I find how to do this? In the Berndt's book "Ramanujan's Notebook, part V" at page 179-180, there is a tentative to explain how

$$\big(t(1-t)\big)^{\frac 1 3}=\frac{2}{3} \frac{2-(G G')^{1/4}} {(G G')^{1/6}}=\frac 2 3 \frac{2+(g g')^{1/4}}{(g g')^{1/6}}$$

using theory "$q_{2}$".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We think to have decrypted the demand equation.
To explain Entry at the buttom of p.25 of the III Ramanujan's Notebook, 
[image]
we think so:

$$\frac{1}{\big(t(1-t)\big)^{\frac 1 3}}=\frac{2}{3} \frac{2-(G G')^{1/4}} {(G G')^{1/6}}=\frac 2 3 \frac{2+(g g')^{1/4}}{(g g')^{1/6}}$$

where

$t=\beta=\alpha_{3n}$ ,  $\frac{1}{G}=G_{9n}^{24}$ and $\frac{1}{G'}=(G_{n})^{24}$

while

$\frac{1}{g}=(g_{9n})^{24}$ and $\frac{1}{g'}=(g_{n})^{24}$

$g_{n}$,$G_{n}$ are Ramanujan's functions (Class Invariants).

1. We show the first identity:

$$\frac{1}{\big(t(1-t)\big)^{\frac 1 3}}=\frac{2}{3} \frac{2-(G G')^{1/4}} {(G G')^{1/6}}$$

From first Entry of page n. 254 of the Chapter XXI of the II Notebook (page numbering of Ramanujan, that here is shown)
[image]

it is clear that

$\beta=\frac{27}{4}\frac{(p+p^{2})^{2}}{(1+p+p^{2})^{3}}$

and the link with $q_{2}$ theory implies that

$\alpha=p^{3}\frac{2+p}{1+2p}$

where $p=\frac{m-1}{2}$ with multiplicator $m$ of degree 3, equal to:

$$m^{2}=1+2 \sqrt{2} \frac{(G_{n})^{3}} {(G_{9n})^{9}}=\frac {9}{1+2\sqrt{2}\frac{(G_{9n})^{3}} {(G_{n})^{9}}}$$

Set

$\rho=\frac{G_{n}}{\sqrt{2}(G_{9n})^{3}}$ and $\tau=\frac{G_{9n}}{\sqrt{2}(G_{n})^{3}}$

then the modular equation of third degree can be written thus:

$$\rho^3=\frac{1-\tau^{3}}{1+8 \tau^{3}}$$

The multiplicator $m$ is: $m^{2}=1+8\rho^{3}$ and although $m=1+2p$, we can write $m^{2}=1+4p+4p^{2}=1+8\rho^{3}$

We have

$p+p^2=2\rho^{3}$.

Then

$$\beta=\frac{27}{4}\frac{(2\rho^{3})^{2}}{(1+2\rho^{3})^3}=\frac{27\rho^{6}}{(1+2\rho^{3})^3}.$$

We need to calculate $(1-\beta)$:

$$(1-\beta)=1-\frac{27\rho^{6}} {(1+2\rho^{3})^3}=\frac{(\rho^{3}-1)^{2}(1+8\rho^{3})} {(1+2\rho^{3})^3}=\frac{27\tau^{6}}{(1+2\tau^{3})^3}$$

Now we observe, always by modular equation of the third degree, that

$$\frac{\tau}{\rho^{2}}+\frac{\rho}{\tau^{2}}=\frac{1}{\rho^{2}\tau^{2}}-8\rho\tau$$.

Then

$\frac{1}{\big(\beta(1-\beta)\big)^{1/3}}=\frac{1+2\rho^{3}} {3\rho^{2}}\frac{1+2\tau^{3}}{3\tau^{2}}$

$=\frac {2}{9}\big(\frac{1}{2\rho^{2}\tau^{2}}+2\rho\tau+\frac{\tau}{\rho^{2}}+\frac{\rho}{\tau^{2}}\big)$

$=\frac{2}{9}\big(\frac{1}{2\rho^{2}\tau^{2}}+2\rho\tau+\frac{1}{\rho^{2}\tau^{2}}-8\rho\tau\big)$

$=\frac {2}{9}\big(\frac{3}{2\rho^{2}\tau^{2}}-6\rho\tau\big)$

$$\frac{1}{\big(\beta(1-\beta)\big)^{1/3}}=\frac {2}{3}\big(\frac{1}{2\rho^{2}\tau^{2}}-2\rho\tau\big)$$

With the following substitutions

$\rho\tau=\frac{G_{n}}{\sqrt{2}(G_{9n})^{3}}\frac{G_{9n}}{\sqrt{2}(G_{n})^{3}}=\frac{1}{2(G_{9n})^{2}(G_{n})^{2}}$

$\frac{1}{\big(\beta(1-\beta)\big)^{1/3}}=\frac{2}{3}\big(2(G_{9n})^{4}(G_{n})^{4}-\frac{1}{(G_{9n})^{2}(G_{n})^{2}}\big)$.

Also we have

$$(G G')^{1/12}=\frac{2}{\rho\tau}=\frac{1}{(G_{9n})^{2}(G_{n})^{2}}$$

At the end we arrive to write

$\frac{1}{\big(\beta(1-\beta)\big)^{1/3}}=\frac{2}{3}\big(\frac{2}{(G G')^{1/6}}-(G G')^{1/12}\big)=$

$$\frac{1}{\big(\beta(1-\beta)\big)^{1/3}}=\frac{2}{3} \frac{2-(G G')^{1/4}} {(G G')^{1/6}}$$

Q.E.D.

2.We 'll show the second identity:

$$\frac{1}{\big(t(1-t)\big)^{\frac 1 3}}=\frac 2 3 \frac{2+(g g')^{1/4}}{(g g')^{1/6}}$$

We set

$r=\frac{g_{n}}{\sqrt{2}(g_{9n})^{3}}$

and

$s=\frac{g_{9n}}{\sqrt{2}(g_{n})^{3}}$

we use the modular equation of third degree for $g_{n}$ and $g_{9n}$:

$$1-8r^{3}=\frac{9}{1+8s^{3}}$$

Setting

$m'=1+2p$ and $m'^{2}=1-8r^{3}$,

the value of $p+p^{2}=-2r^{3}$,

moreover the value of singular modulus will be:

$\beta=\frac{27}{4}\frac{(-2r^{3})^{2}}{(1-2r^{3})^{3}}$

that is equal to:

$\beta=\frac{27r^{6}}{(1-2r^{3})^{3}}$

It is necessary to calculate $(1-\beta)$:

$(1-\beta)=1-\frac{27r^{6}}{(1-2r^{3})^{3}}=\frac{(r^{3}+1)^{2}(1-8r^{3})}{(1-2r^{3})^{3}}=\frac{27s^{6}}{(1+2s^{3})^{3}}$

Now we observe by the modular equation of the third degree that

$$\frac{s}{r^{2}}-\frac{r}{s^{2}}=\frac{1}{r^{2}s^{2}}+8rs$$

Thus

$\frac{1}{\big(\beta(1-\beta)\big)^{1/3}}=\frac{(1-2r^{3})} {3 r^{2}}\frac{(1+2 s^{3})}{3 s^{2}}$

$=\frac {2}{9}\big(\frac{1}{2 r^{2} s^{2}}-2 r s+\frac{s}{r^{2}}-\frac{r}{s^{2}}\big)$

$=\frac{2}{9}\big(\frac{1}{2 r^{2}s^{2}}-2 r s+\frac{1}{r^{2}s^{2}}+8 r s\big)$

$=\frac {2}{9}\big(\frac{3}{2 r^{2}s^{2}}+6 r s\big)$

$$\frac{1}{\big(\beta(1-\beta)\big)^{1/3}}=\frac {2}{3}\big(\frac{1}{2 r^{2} s^{2}}+2 r s\big)$$

Also we have

$$r s=\frac{g_{n}}{\sqrt{2} (g_{9n})^{3}}\frac{g_9n}{(\sqrt{2}g_{n})^{3}}=\frac{1}{2 (g_{9n}g_{n})^{2}}$$

Moreover

$$\frac{1}{\big(\beta(1-\beta)\big)^{1/3}}=\frac{2}{3}\big(2(g_{9n}g_{n})^{4}+\frac{1}{(g_{9n}g_{n})^{2}}\big)$$

Also we have

$(g g')^{1/12}=\frac{1}{(g_{9n}g_{n})^{2}}$

making substitution in the last expression we arrive at

$$\frac{1}{\big(\beta(1-\beta)\big)^{1/3}}=\frac {2} {3} \big(\frac{2}{(g g')^{1/6}}+{(g g')^{1/12}}\big)$$

$$=\frac 2 3 \frac{2+(g g')^{1/4}}{(g g')^{1/6}}$$

Q.E.D.

Now the link between $q_{3}$ theory and $q_{2}$ theory:

$$\big(\frac{1} {\alpha_{3n}}\big)^{1/3}=\frac{2}{3} \frac{(G_{9n})^{6}}{(G_{n})^{2}}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3} \frac{G_{n}} {(G_{9n})^{3}}$$

$$\big(\frac{1} {\alpha_{3n}}\big)^{1/3}=\frac{2}{3}\frac{(g_{9n})^{6}} {(g_{n})^{2}}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\frac{g_{n}}{(g_{9n})^{3}}$$

$$\big(\frac{1}{\beta_{3n}}\big)^{1/3}=\frac{2}{3}\frac{(G_{n})^{6}}{(G_{9n})^{2}}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\frac{G_{9n}}{(G_{n})^{3}}$$

$$\big(\frac{1}{\beta_{3n}}\big)^{1/3}=\frac{2}{3}\frac{(g_{n})^{6}} {(g_{9n})^{2}}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\frac{g_{9n}}{(g_{n})^{3}}$$

Knowing the invariant values $G_{n}$, $G_{9n}$, $g_{n}$ and $g_{9n}$, we calculated
the first ten singular moduli:

$\alpha_{1}=\frac{1}{2}$

$\alpha_{2}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$

$\alpha_{3}=\big(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}\big)^3$

$\alpha_{4}=\frac{9-5\sqrt{3}}{18}$

$\alpha_{5}=\frac{25-11\sqrt{5}}{50}$

$\alpha_{6}=\big(\frac{4-\sqrt{6}}{10}\big)^3$

$\alpha_{7}=\frac{18-13\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{21}}{36}$

$\alpha_{8}=\frac{2-17\sqrt{2}+9\sqrt{6}}{4}$

$\alpha_{9}=\big(\frac{2^{1/3}-1}{2^{1/3}+2}\big)^3$

$\alpha_{10}=\frac{54-35\sqrt{2}-2\sqrt{5}}{108}$

These solve:

$$\frac{\,_2F_1\big(\tfrac13,\tfrac23,1,\,1-\alpha_n\big)}{\,_2F_1\big(\tfrac13,\tfrac23,1,\,\alpha_n\big)} =\sqrt{n}$$

Other applications:

1. Given $n=3$,$\alpha_{3n}=\alpha_{9}=?$,

$G_{n}=G_{3}=2^{1/12}$,

$G_{9n}=G_{27}=\frac{2^{1/12}}{(2^{1/3}-1)^{1/3}}$

$$\alpha_{9}=\frac{1+3 2^{1/3}-3 2^{2/3}}{2(2^{2/3}+1)^{3}}=\bigg(\frac{2^{1/3}-1}{2^{1/3}+2}\bigg)^3$$

2. Given $n=2$, $\alpha_{3n}=\alpha_{6}=?$,

   $g_{n}=g_{2}=1$, $g_{9n}=g_{18}=(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})^{1/3}$

$$\frac{1}{(\alpha_{6})^{1/3}}=4+\sqrt{6}$$

3. Given

   $n=\frac{4}{3}$,

$\alpha_{3n}=\alpha_{4}=?$,

$g_{n}=g_{4/3}=2^{1/6}\big(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}\big)^{1/4}$,

$g_{9n}=g_{12}=2^{1/6}\big(\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{\sqrt{2}}\big)^{1/4}$

$$(\frac{1}{\beta_{4}})^{1/3}=\frac{\sqrt{3}(\sqrt{3}-1)}{2^{1/3}}$$

$$\beta_{4}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{5 \sqrt{3}}{18}.$$

and so on...

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I do not know if I have to edit my script, after his report or leave it as it is.

Comment: As not said, I just saw that the fix is already done.!

Comment: It's perfect! Thanks again.

Comment: No, no. I don't know how to do it!

Comment: I suggest sending him email. I will do it myself later after I have written up a detailed account of my checking of your equations which is how I found your few typos.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I would add that the mysterious equation with $\,^{\sqrt[3]{}}\!t(1-t)\,$ is printed in the second volume of his _Notebooks_ on what should have been page 392 (but that page is unnumbered and the image is printed upside down!)

Comment: Also I would specify that right at the sign "/" the sheet is torn however imperceptibly you notice the fraction sign!