# Ratio of theta functions as roots of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, special-functions, radicals, closed-form, theta-functions

I was playing with the theta functions with argument $ z = 0 $

$ \vartheta_2(q) =\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{(n+1/2)^2} $

$ \vartheta_3(q) =\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{n^2} $

$ \vartheta_4(q) =\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^nq^{n^2} $

And I noticed that the ratio $ \frac{\vartheta_4(e^{-2\pi})}{\vartheta_3(e^{-2\pi})}$ is the root of this minimal polynomial $x^8+32x^4-32$, so I kept going and I found the same kind of relation between these ratios and  minimal polynomials

$\frac{\vartheta_4(e^{-3\pi})}{\vartheta_3(e^{-3\pi})}$ is the root of $16x^{16} - 32 x^{12} + 792 x^8 - 776 x^4 + 1$

$\frac{\vartheta_3(e^{-3\pi})}{\vartheta_2(e^{-3\pi})}$ is the root of $x^{16} - 776 x^{12} + 792 x^8 - 32 x^4 + 16$

$\frac{\vartheta_3(e^{-2\pi})}{\vartheta_2(e^{-2\pi})}$ is the root of $x^2 - 2 x - 1$

$\frac{\vartheta_3(e^{-4\pi})}{\vartheta_2(e^{-4\pi})}$ is the root of $x^4 - 12 x^3 + 6 x^2 - 12 x + 1$

$\frac{\vartheta_3(e^{-5\pi})}{\vartheta_2(e^{-5\pi})}$ is the root of $x^{16} - 414728 x^{12} + 414744 x^8 - 32 x^4 + 16$

$\frac{\vartheta_4(e^{-2\pi})}{\vartheta_2(e^{-2\pi})}$ is the root of $x^8 - 32 x^4 - 32$

$\frac{\vartheta_4(e^{-3\pi})}{\vartheta_2(e^{-3\pi})}$ is the root of $x^4 - 4 x^3 - 6 x^2 - 4 x + 1$

$\frac{\vartheta_4(e^{-5\pi})}{\vartheta_2(e^{-5\pi})}$ is the root of $x^4 - 24 x^3 - 34 x^2 - 24 x + 1$

Those polynomials show up in other problems? Their coefficients could be found in any sequence?

**Edit**: I did some little progress, and using the notations given by the user Somos in his answer, we have this table

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
 n  &  P_n(x) & Q_n(x) & R_n(x) \\ \hline
 1 & x^4-2      & x-1          & 2x^4-1        \\ \hline
 2 & x^4-2x^2-1 & x^8-4x^4-4   & x^8+4x^4-4    \\ \hline
 3 & x^8-16x^4+16 & x^4-4x^2+1 & 16x^8-16x^4+1 \\ \hline
 4 & x^2-2x-1   & x^8-32x^4-32 & x^8+32x^4-32  \\ \hline
5 & x^{16} - 72x^{12} + 88x^8 - 32x^4 + 16   & x^4 - 2x^3 - 2x^2 - 2x + 1 & 16x^{16} - 32x^{12} + 88x^8 - 72 x^4 + 1 \\ \hline
6 & x^8 - 12x^6 + 2x^4 + 12x^2 + 1 & x^{16} - 136x^{12} - 120x^8 + 32 x^4 + 16 & x^{16} + 136x^{12} - 120x^8 - 32 x^4 + 16 \\ \hline
7 & x^8 - 256 x^4 + 256 & x^4 - 16x^2 + 1 & 256x^8 - 256x^4 + 1 \\ \hline
8 & x^4 - 4 x^3 - 2 x^2 - 4 x + 1 & x^{16} - 448x^{12} - 1472x^8 - 2048x^4 - 1024 & x^{16} + 448x^{12} - 1472x^8 + 2048x^4 - 1024 \\ \hline
9 & x^{16} - 776x^{12} + 792x^8 - 32x^4 + 16 & x^4 - 4x^3 - 6x^2 - 4x + 1 & 16x^{16} - 32x^{12} + 792x^8 - 776x^4 + 1 \\ \hline
10 & x^8 - 36x^6 + 2x^4 + 36x^2 + 1 & x^{16} - 1288x^{12} - 1272 x^8 + 32 x^4 + 16 & x^{16} + 1288x^{12} - 1272x^8 - 32 x^4 + 16 \\ \hline
\end{array}

As you can clearly notice, some patterns shows up: when $ n $ is odd $ P_n(x) $ and $ R_n(x) $ are [reciprocal polynomials](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial), while when $ n $ is even $ Q_n(x) $ and $ R_n(x) $ are equal except for the sign of the second and second-last coefficient.

Answer (score 9):

The question is about the irreducible polynomials of the ratio of
theta-null values. The context is *singular moduli*. That is, define
for convenience, $\,q_n:=\exp(-\pi\sqrt{n}).\,$ Then it is known that

$$ k = k(q_n) := (\vartheta_2(q_n)/\vartheta_3(q_n))^2 $$

is an algebraic number and known as a *singular modulus*. Because
of the identity

$$ \vartheta_3(q)^4 = \vartheta_4(q)^4 + \vartheta_2(q)^4, $$

if the quotient of any pair of these theta-null values is
algebraic, then all of the quotients pairs are.

Define the irreducible polynomial $P_n(x)$ such that
$\,P_n(\vartheta_3(q_n)/\vartheta_2(q_n))=0.\,$
Similarly, define irreducible polynomial $Q_n(x)$ such that
$\,Q_n(\vartheta_4(q_n)/\vartheta_2(q_n))=0\,$ and
$R_n(x)$ such that
$\,R_n(\vartheta_4(q_n)/\vartheta_3(q_n))=0.\,$

The following is a small table of polynomial sequence values:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
 n  &  P_n(x) & Q_n(x) & R_n(x) \\ \hline
 1 & x^4-2      & x-1          & 2x^4-1        \\ \hline
 2 & x^4-2x^2-1 & x^8-4x^4-4   & x^8+4x^4-4    \\ \hline
 3 & x^8-16x^4+16 & x^4-4x^2+1 & 16x^8-16x^4+1 \\ \hline
 4 & x^2-2x-1   & x^8-32x^4-32 & x^8+32x^4-32  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

The basic facts about the modular properties of theta-nulls are

$$ \vartheta_2(q_{1/n}) = n^{1/4}\vartheta_4(q_n), \\
\vartheta_3(q_{1/n}) = n^{1/4}\vartheta_3(q_n), \\
\vartheta_4(q_{1/n}) = n^{1/4}\vartheta_2(q_n). \tag1 $$

Other basic facts relating theta-nulls to the
[Arithmetic-Geometric Mean](https://dlmf.nist.gov/22.20.ii) are

$$
 \vartheta_3(q^2)^2\!=\!\frac{\vartheta_3(q)^2\!+\!\vartheta_4(q)^2}2,\\
 \vartheta_4(q^2)^2 \!=\! \vartheta_3(q) \vartheta_4(q), \\
 \vartheta_2(q^2)^2 \!=\! \frac{\vartheta_3(q)^2\!-\!\vartheta_4(q)^2}2.
 \tag2 $$

Define the theta-null quotient functions as

$$ p(x) :=\vartheta_3(x)/\vartheta_2(x), \qquad
r(x) :=\vartheta_4(x)/\vartheta_3(x). \tag3$$

Notice that

$$ r(q^2)^2 = \frac{\vartheta_4(q^2)^2}{\vartheta_3(q^2)^2} =
 \frac{2\vartheta_3(q) \vartheta_4(q)}{\vartheta_3(q)^2 +
 \vartheta_4(q)^2} = \frac{2r(q)}{1+r(q)}. \tag4$$

Use the modular properties in equation $(1)$ to get

$$ r(q_{1/n}) = \vartheta_2(q_n)/\vartheta_3(q_n) = 1/p(q_n). \tag5$$

In equation $(4)$ use the substitution $\,q = q_{1/2}\,$ to get

$$ 1/p(q_{1/2}) = r(q_2) = \sqrt{2r(q_{1/2})/(1+r(q_{1/2})^2)}. \tag6 $$

Use the known identity among theta-nulls to get

$$ \vartheta_3(x)^4 = \vartheta_4(x)^4 \!+\!
 \vartheta_2(x)^4, \; 1 = r(x)^4 \!+\! 
 1/p(x)^4. \tag7 $$

Combine these two previous equations and solve to get
$$ p(q_{1/2}) = \Big(1/2 \!+\!
 \sqrt{1/2}\Big)^{1/4},\; 
  r(q_{1/2}) = \sqrt{\sqrt{2}\!-\!1}. \tag8 $$

Now compute $\,p(q_2), r(q_2)\,$ and verify that they
satisfy $\,P_2(x)=0, R_2(x)=0\,$ respectively.

Use a similar method to find the values of $\,p(q_n), q(q_n), r(q_n)\,$
for other positive integer values of $n$ using the algebraic relations
between $\,\vartheta_2(q),$ $\vartheta_3(q),$ $\vartheta_4(q)\,$ and
$\,\vartheta_2(q^n),$ $\vartheta_3(q^n),$ $\vartheta_4(q^n).\,$

---

Remark: Not exactly about ratio of theta-nulls but you may find the interesting
[MSE question 2104356](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2104356)
worth reading.

Comment: Thank you! Those coefficients could be expressed in some other way?

Comment: @user967210: there is no systematic pattern of the coefficients satisfied by singular moduli. A lot of their algebraic properties are handled more properly using modular forms, but I don't think even the modular forms give a clear pattern for the coefficients of their minimal polynomials.

Comment: Put $\tau_n = i \sqrt{n}/2$, so $q_n = \exp(2 \pi i \tau_n)$. You are computing ratios of $\theta$ functions at $\tau_n$. These ratios of $\theta$ functions are weight $0$ modular forms, which means that their value only depends on the lattice $\Lambda_n = \mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z} \tau_n$. The special thing about $\Lambda_n$ is that $(2 \sqrt{-n} i) \Lambda_n \subset \Lambda_n$. (continued)

Comment: Whenever you have two lattices $L_1 \subset L_2$ (other than $k L \subset L$), and a weight $0$ modular form $f$, you get a polynomial relationship between $f(L_1)$ and $f(L_2)$, which in this case is a polynomial relation between $f(\Lambda_n)$ and itself. (PS I suspect I might have some inappropriate $2$'s in this comment. I put them in to match the usual definition $q = \exp(2 \pi i \tau)$ and Somos' definition $q_n = \exp(- \pi \sqrt{n})$, but I am not confident they all wound up in the right place.)